# how to stop Outlook adding space after backslash

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, autocorrect

I was going to ask this and then figured it out. I assume this applies to Word as well.
If you type something in an email with a backslash and then paste something at the end, it automatically adds a space, which is undesirable. So, "c:\more\" becomes "c:\more\ stuff" instead of c:\more\stuff".

Answer (score 2):

To stop this, click the file menu > options > (in mail menu) Spelling and Autocorrect button > Advanced menu (on left) > scroll to Cut, Copy, paste section >  at "use smart cut and paste" item, click Settings button > uncheck first item, "Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically".